# mail() - emails work but SMS doesn't

Tags: php, email, sms

I am trying to send SMS using php's `mail()` function. Below you will find my code. I entered my own email address and my own phone number (it is a Verizon phone so sending an email to my 10 digit number followed by @vtext.com should send the SMS to my phone).  I receive the email but not the text message.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?
    require_once("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.fas.harvard.edu";

    $mail->SetFrom("example@gmail.com");
    $mail->AddAddress("##########@vtext.com");
    $mail->AddAddress("example@gmail.com");

    $mail->Subject = "hello, world";
    $mail->Body = "testing 1 2 3";

    if ($mail->Send() === false)
        die($mail->ErrorInfo . "\n");  

?>
```

Comment: Do you have somewhere error messages?

Comment: no, i'm not receiving an error message.  I just don't receive an SMS. The bool (for mail()) returns true when I use echo to print it out, but I don't actually receive the SMS

Comment: @user1084785: Send an email to the address you have in place of `##########@vtext.com` and tell us if you receive an email. It may not be even related to your script - it may be related to this external service (maybe some lags, maybe messages are blocked etc.).

Comment: sending an email to the address I have at ##########@vtext.com does work when i do it from my gmail account.

Comment: @user1084785: Are there not even error messages in the mail server log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use the emails in another way, like:

```
$mail->AddCC("woot@gmail.com");
```

Also, are you sure that your SMTP server is not blocked by Gmail? have you tried any other email address?

Comment: woo hoo!!!! it seems to work when i don't use a gmail account.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's being sent as HTML. Try

```
$mail->ContentType = 'text/plain';  
$mail->IsHTML(false);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and it still doesn't work.  Any other thoughts?